# How do I code Shift + Left Arrow key in VBA Excel to change my range?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new with VBA and wanted to create a VBA program to automatically block one column to the left from the right side, here's a picture for example: [image]

And make it into like so:

[image]

I'm trying to use offsets to do that but I'm not sure which value I should use because value of (-1) exert to the left column and (1) did the same on the right.

here's my code:

```
Sub Macro47()
'
' Macro47 Macro
'
'
Range("B2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    'Debug.Print ActiveCell.Address
    Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(0, -1)).Select


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid using `Select`.

You can achieve the same thing you want with this:

```vb
Sub Macro47()
'
' Macro47 Macro
'
'
Dim lCol As Long, lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Set the Worksheet you want the Address of

With ws
    lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1 'Find right most Column, subtract 1 for the 'Total' Column
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row

    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))

    Debug.Print rng.Address
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried using this code but it didn't do anything, didn't throw no errors either. :/

Comment: @MikhailS it will print the Address to the Immidiate Window (In VBA-Editor press `Ctrl`+`G`)

Comment: @MikhailS if you want the `Range` to be selected, just add `rng.Select` after the `Set rng = ...`

Comment: Works!! Thanks alot chief Appreciate it!!

Comment: @MikhailS If the this answers your question, can you mark it as answer? Thanks!